# Check if bit sequence exists in binary representation

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I wrote some code to check if a bit sequence can be found within a different bit sequence.

For example, below, the bit sequence of 9 is found in the bit sequence of 25, but not in that of 15.

The way I'm doing this now is to take the string binary representation and run a regex to check if one matches the other. Ideally I'd like to do this using bitwise operations, and I've looked at the [bitwise operation truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Truth_table_for_all_binary_logical_operators) and apparently [XNOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate) looks like it would do what I need.. but I haven't had much success with it.

How would you do this type of matching using bitwise operations?

Thanks

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
N=9
H1=15
H2=25
for x in [N,H1,H2]:
    print('{:032b}'.format(x))

Nb,H1b,H2b=[format(x,"b") for x in [N,H1,H2]]
import re
for x in [H1b,H2b]:
    print(bool(re.search(Nb,x)))
```

Comment: XNOR can be achieved by e.g.`(~(N^H1))`, but could you please elaborate why do you think XNOR is the solution? what will you check on the XNOR's result to determine if it is true or false?

Comment: I was thinking to check   `(~(N^H1))==N` but I tried that and the XNOR gave a negative result, which.. is far from what I was expecting. But then maybe that's because the XNOR in Python is performed on signed integers. The reason why I mentioned XNOR is because its table looks like a bit-by-bit equality check and that made it seem like a good fit.

Comment: It gives you all 1s if the bits are completely equal, we can use that to determine if the bit pattern is contained "aligned right". but let's say, what about `H3 = 51`? `N = 9`'s bit pattern is still contained in it (and your regex solution will indeed return true), but any bit-wise solution will require some shifting, this becomes much less elegant.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 it's fine to only handle the aligned case. The other ones can be handled by shifting N in different positions.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your bit string and patterns are not to long (ie they fit in a long long), here is how it can be written in C.

```
// searchs if pattern is present within  bit string tosearch
// patternlenth is the number of bits in the pattern
// returns the required shift for the firt match is found
// assumes the number of bits in tosearch bit sting is 64
// returns -1 is pattern is not found
int bitstringsearch(unsigned long long tosearch, long long pattern, int patternlength){
  long long mask = (1<<patternlength) -1 ;
  // mask is a set of patternlength consecutive ones at lsb
  printf("%llx\n",mask);
  for (int i=0; i<64-patternlength; i++){
    if ( (~(tosearch ^ pattern) & mask) == mask)
      // checks is the patternlenth LSB bits of tosearch are equal
      //  to pattern
      return i;  // yes, returns the current shift
    tosearch >>=1;  // shift bitsting to search search
  }
  return -1;  // not found
}
```

The translation in python should obvious. This can easily be extended to search for all matches.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that this can be achieved by checking some (simple) relationship between the 2 numbers, but I can't put my finger on it. Below it's an alternative.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import math


def get_mask(n, base=2):
    magnitude = math.ceil(math.log(n, base))
    return base ** magnitude - 1


def contains_binary(container, containee):
    mask = get_mask(containee)
    while containee <= container:
        if container & mask == containee:
            return True
        containee <<= 1
        mask <<= 1
    return False


def main():
    op1 = 9
    numbers = [
        0,
        1,
        8,
        9,
        15,
        18,
        25,
        51,
        54,
        90,
        549,
        17477,
    ]
    for op0 in numbers:
        print("{0:d} ({1:s}) contains {2:d} ({3:s}): {4:}".format(op0, bin(op0)[2:], op1, bin(op1)[2:], contains_binary(op0, op1)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Notes**:

- Works on **unsigned values only**
- *get_mask*: gets the number *bit* (actually, digit) count, and makes it all ***1*** (*BASE - 1*) (probably this is the *nxor* equivalent)
- *contains_binary*: moves *containee* and its *bit* mask window from right to left in *container*

  - *and*s (binary) the mask to zero out all *container*'s bits outside of the window
  - Checks the result against *containee*

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057744847]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> 0 (0) contains 9 (1001): False
> 1 (1) contains 9 (1001): False
> 8 (1000) contains 9 (1001): False
> 9 (1001) contains 9 (1001): True
> 15 (1111) contains 9 (1001): False
> 18 (10010) contains 9 (1001): True
> 25 (11001) contains 9 (1001): True
> 51 (110011) contains 9 (1001): True
> 54 (110110) contains 9 (1001): False
> 90 (1011010) contains 9 (1001): False
> 549 (1000100101) contains 9 (1001): True
> 17477 (100010001000101) contains 9 (1001): False
>
> Done.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

to check if your sequence Nb is in the other sequence you can use:

```
H1b.find(Nb) != -1
H2b.find(Nb) != -1
```

or you can use:

```
Nb in H1b
Nb in H2b
```